# Grabbing parent text using .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting the text 'Vegetable' from the DOM

```
   <div class="input-group">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="input-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
            </span>
            Vegetable
        </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Currently, I have an event handler for when I check the box to grab the text of the element of the list, but what I am doing is not working: `$(e.target).parent().text()`. My thinking was that I am targeting `"input-checkbox"`, so i need to get the parent and then grab the text of it. Is that the right approach or is it something wrong with my jQuery?

Events Code:

```
Template.produceList.events({
    'click .input-checkbox': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked on filter');
        var text = $(e.target).parent().text();
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to get the parent of the parent of the target - see how your input is the child of the span, but the span does not contain the word you're looking for, it's the parent of the span, the li that has that text, so, parent of parent

Comment: Similar to my comment below, why am i starting at input instead of span? I thought I was targeting clicks on input-checkbox".

Comment: If you can post your code which connects the onclick event, it would help to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go two levels up because "input" is inside "span" which is inside "li", and the text "Vegetable" is inside "li".

```
$(e.target).parent().parent().text()
```

I have created an example here (it's a little modified form of your code):
https://jsfiddle.net/x5yb2m30/

Another way to do this would be to use parents() and look for li tag:

```
$(e.target).parents("li").text()
```

Comment: Interesting. Even though I was targeting a click action on "input-checkbox", I am starting from `<input>`? Why is that the case? Oh btw it worked, so thanks alot!

Comment: I don't know where your click even is bound to, I was guessing

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery `this` is the element the event is registered against, the target is the DOM node that acted on the event.  In this case, the `event.target` is the input field itself.

```
// this will give you the expected container 
// regardless of the child element the target belongs to
$(event.target).closest('li');
```

As an aside, I suggest the following structure for checkboxes and radio buttons.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" ... />
  <span>Text Goes Here</span>
</label>
```

This way, the label itself will target the input for clicking... beyond this, you can use an adjacent sibling selector to override display behavior if you're using a graphical font like fontawesome for checkboxes

```
label + input[type=checkbox] { display:none }
label > input[type=checkbox] + span:before { 
  /*setup for glyph font character*/
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f096"; //square-o
  color:#000;
}
label > input[type=checkbox]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f046"; //check-square-o 
}
label > input[type=checkbox]:disabled + span:before {
  color:#888;
}
```

Also, I would suggest using `data-` attributes on your selected container for whatever data you need access to, don't rely on the text itself.  Either have values and/or data on the input elements themselves, or the appropriate container.

ex:

```
<label data-category="foo">
    <input id="chkFoo" type="checkbox" value="bar" />
    <span>Foo</span>
</label>
```

You can access data via. `$('#chkFoo').val()` or `$('#chkFoo').parent().data('category')` which is easier to reason with, and can remain consistent regardless of display text, which may be localized in a given application.

Comment: So just to be clear, `$('#chkFoo').val() or $('#chkFoo').parent().data('category')` would both return `Foo`?

Comment: Category is foo, val is bar.  The point is you shouldn't rely on the text in a given node to determine state... It should be a value or a data attribute

Comment: Right and that definitely is a cleaner and more robust way of approaching it. I am just confused as to what the two jQuery calls return. Does the first return val and the second return foo?

Comment: `.val()` returns the checkbox's value, which is "bar", the .data('category') will return the label's data-category of "foo"

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks alot!